# C# Http Request with Authentication

Tags: c#, http, authentication, httprequest, http-get

I need your help and all other questions didn't work out for me.

I want to program a simple Http request with C#. After that it should be a http get. But the API I want to request requires authentication.

I can connect with the server but I don't know how to program the
authentication for that.

Username and password are both "test"

```
public static class HttpGet
{
    static void Main()
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    public static HttpClient ApiCLient { get; set; }
    
    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        string username = "test";
        string password = "test";

        using (var ApiCLient = new HttpClient())
        {
            ApiCLient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44325/");
            ApiCLient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            ApiCLient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiCLient.GetAsync("weatherforecast");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ddd");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me. Every solution I tried didn't work for me...

Thank you :)

(I am new to ASP.NET)

Comment: Maybe`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue(username, password)`

Comment: we need to know how it authorizes,  some use basic auth, some have keys / tokens.  Usually they are  some kind of request header.   There are standard and non standard ways people do authorization/authentication

Comment: im sorry, after the authentification, I will get a token

Comment: So perfect would be an authentification and after that the token should be return and displayed in the console

Comment: When the authetification was correct, then i will get a token and this token should displayed in the console

Comment: We cant help you, it seems you have no idea about the actual authentication method or what is required to access this resource other then a user name and password, which is insufficient information to proceed.

Comment: Do you know how to log onto the system using your browser? You can record the traffic with Chrome tools to figure out what you're supposed to be sending.

Comment: the server is running local, but when i try to log on in the browser ist only says, that the site is not availble

Comment: If the server is local, can you check its configuration to see what sort of authentication it requires?

Comment: Where exectally can i find it?
Can i find it in Postman or in the code? :)
Thank you for your help

Comment: The Token ist for the bearer Token authentification

Comment: sounds like an typical oauth. So first you have to call the authentication api, which returns the authentication token, which can be delivered in your request header as authorization bearer TOKEN